# How to log in via ssh to a newly created virtual machine at Hetzner

Tags: virtualhost, ssh

I've purchased the cheapest virtual server (20GB, 2RAM, 1VCPU for 2.96€) at [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.com/) and can not log in to it - a password is requested and I have no idea what password it should be.  What I've tried so far:

- to add new ssh key (id_rsa.pub one) via web interface and log in using the user with this key
- to enter my account password via console
- to enter my account password via web console
- to generate ssh key via `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N '' -t ed25519` and use id instead of id_rsa.pub
- follow instructions provided here - http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/server-administration/openssh-keys-certificates-authentication-pem-pub-crt

Documentation is not helpful either. I've immediately reached support but so far they hadn't answered. I've thought that even if I'm stupid and missing something quite obvious - still from statistical point of view there's a probability that someone else is equally stupid - so may be an answer to this question would be helpful not only for me.

Comment: Not directly related, but maybe helpful: In may case I could not login after restoring a backup - I simply forgot, that the ssh port on the server has been changed (not 22) - so I simply had to use the right port when connecting to the machine

Answer (score 2):

So let my own answer be here (support helped me) - hopefully somebody else will find solution quicker. So, if you've created server with ssh key provided you won't get any password by e-mail. The question why my ssh keys were not valid is still unsolved for me however you can easily reset password in cloud console via "RESCUE" option.

Comment: my problem is that I've uploaded a public ssh key via hetzner UI from Mac and now I'm trying to do the same from Ubuntu and it's not working. I still can log in into VM from Mac. I don't even have a password on the vm, only ssh access.

Comment: Same problem here. I removed the ssh keys and set a root password via rescue, but still it says wrong password. :(

Answer (score 2):

What helped me is connecting with user root: `ssh root@YOURIP`